Linux kernel prroblem with RAID: megaraid_sas 0000:43:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0xa518d000 flags=0x0020]
After upgrating Proxmox from 7.2 to 8.2 and Linux kernel from 5.x to 6.8.4-2-pve (Proxmox) I have problems with
kernel module megaraid_sas for AVAGO MegaRAID SAS 9440-8i controller.
Server starts but when I powerup virtual machines after few minutes I got errors:
Oct 12 00:16:00 host6 kernel: megaraid_sas 0000:43:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0xa518d000 flags=0x0020]
Oct 12 00:16:00 host6 kernel: megaraid_sas 0000:43:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000e address=0xa518dd00 flags=0x0020]

After that whole server hangs since system is remounting to read only:
EXT4-fs error (device dm-4): ext4_journal_check_start:84 comm pvescheduler: Detected aborted journal
EXT4-fs error (device dm-4): ext4_journal_check_start:84 comm rm:main R:Reg Detected aborted journal
EXT4-fs error (device dm-4): Remounting filesystem read-only

Controller: AVAGO MegaRAID SAS 9440-8i
Firmware version: 5.220.01-3691
I think problem is connected with kernel itself so maybe some of you have similar problem.
The problem is not connected with update procedure itself because when I installed on the same server new Proxmox from scratch I had the same problem.
Thanks is advance.

The documentation specifies upgrading from version 7.4. Is that the steps performed?

@GregAskew thanks for hint but the problem is not connected with update procedure itself because when  I installed on the same server new Proxmox from scratch I had the same problem.

There were some reported problems with Proxmox when using kernel 6.8. Try dropping back to kernel 6.5.
